# Selecting multiple rows and returning the sum in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following subset:

```
   ICD10      n
   <chr>  <int>
1    X74 124533
2    X70  94313
3    X72  46891
4    X64  33179
5    X73  31722
6    X67  12776
7    X61  10291
8    X80   8543
9    X62   7255
10   X78   7175
```

The column `ICD10` has a code like `X73`. I would like to select three of them and return the sum. Something like this:

```
x <- data %>%
filter(ICD10 == 'X74' & ICD10 == 'X72' & ICD10 == 'X73') %>%
summarise(sum(n))
```

How can I get this code to work properly?

Comment: You just need "or" (`|`) instead of "and" (`&`). Alternately, you can use `%in%` to put them all in one condition: `filter(ICD10 %in% c('X74', 'X72', 'X73'))`

Comment: `|` returns `0`. That is `or` operator. I do need 3 of the rows and sum them.

Comment: `|` works for me: `data %>%
    filter(ICD10 == 'X74' | ICD10 == 'X72' | ICD10 == 'X73') %>%
    summarise(sum(n))`, but I'd probably use `%in%` for concision.

Comment: It is weird. I have double check my subset and everything looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `%in%`

```
tbl_df(df1) %>% 
          filter(ICD10 %in% c('X74', 'X72', 'X73')) %>%
          summarise(Sum = sum(n))
#    Sum
#1 203146
```

---

But, this can be done with `base R`

```
sum(subset(df1,  ICD10 %in% c('X74', 'X72', 'X73'), select = n)[,1])
#[1] 203146
```

Comment: `suicide.by.icd10 %>%
  filter(ICD10 %in% c('X74', 'X73', 'X72')) %>%
  summarise(Sum = sum(n))`

Comment: @Gilbert Here, I get the 201346

Comment: Yes I see that returns `203146`

Comment: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables`

Comment: @Gilbert I guess there is something wrong in your data i.e  check the `str(suicide.by.icd10)` to see if 'n' is `numeric` or not.

Comment: It is a `tbl_df` and `data.frame` since I'm utilizing dplyr. ICD10: chr and n: int

Comment: It is a dplyr function to convert R data frames into local dlpyr data.frame.

Comment: @Gilbert I tried converting to `tbl_df` and still it works

Comment: Wow!!! With this code: `suicide.by.icd10 %>%
  filter(ICD10 %in% c('X74', 'X73', 'X72')) %>%
  summarise(Sum = sum(n))` I get this result.... `Source: local data frame [1 x 1]

    Sum
  <int>
1     0`

Comment: @Gilbert Can you use `dplyr::summarise(Sum = sum(n))`

Comment: With this code `dplyr::summarise(.data = suicide.by.icd10, Sum = sum(n))` I get 398047

Comment: @Glibert I meant to use it with whole chain i.e. `suicide.by.icd10 %>% filter(ICD10 %in% c('X74', 'X73', 'X72')) %>% dplyr::summarise(Sum= sum(n))`

Comment: `    Sum
  <int>
1     0`

Comment: @Gilbert If it doesn't work, try `suicide.by.icd10 %>% filter(trimws(ICD10) %in% c('X74', 'X73', 'X72')) %>% dplyr::summarise(Sum = sum(n))`  This is to ensure that if you have leading/lagging spaces in the 'ICD10', we strip it off

Comment: Need to read about trimws!!!! I see that is a {base} R function. What does in short?

Comment: @Gilbert In short if you have `" X73" or `"X74 "` or `" X73 "`, it gives `"X73", `"X74"`, `"X73"`

Comment: I read that trims all white spaces from strings. That is a bug of dlpyr. suicide.by.icd10 was created with this code `suicide.by.icd10 <- suicide.10.years %>%
  count(ICD10) %>%
  filter(n > 100)`

Comment: @Gilbert You can check the `suicide.10.years$ICD10` to see if there are leading/lagging spaces